# How to create a header file from a C code file so that it can be used in another program?

Tags: c

Let's say I have a file with a couple of functions, written in C.

What should I do to turn that file into a header file, so that I can `#include` it into programs in future?

Comment: Write a header with the declarations you want to export. If you want to export everything, for functions, just strip out all the function definitions and replace it with a semicolon.

For example, `int add_one(int x) { x + 1; }` would be `int add_one(int x);` in the header.


But it's what **you** want to export. Technically, even without a header you do: `extern int add_one(int x);` and still call it from a different source file. Headers are what **you** want to export.

Comment: do you want those functions to be visible to anyone that gets/ uses your h file, or just their declarations ?

Comment: you can include it as is. use `#pragma once`

Comment: You *don't* convert simple files with C code into headers, because that will lead to linking errors or duplicated code and variables. Instead you will create a library, and the header file will just contain the headers - function declarations, variable *declarations* and necessary type definitions. Then the actual code would be in a separate translation unit, or a library

Answer (score 2):

#include just copy pastes the file in place. You don't have to do anything to make a file "includable."

That said, there are some best practices:

- Only put declarations in the header files.  Put implementation in a .c file which you then compile to a .o file.  Then link your .o files.  This will prevent repeat compilation.
- Include all headers that the to-be-included file needs.  This way the header will be able to be included in any order.
- Consider adding [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)
- You should consider prefixing your functions and variables e.g. MyLib_...

Comment: *Only put definitions in the header files.* should say *Only put declarations in the header files.*